# How can I pull title of current page into a URL/src?

Tags: javascript, html, page-title

I'm looking to pull the title of the current page into an img src URL.

For instance:

```
<title>booth106</title>
<img src="https://mywebsite.com/booth106/images/picture1.jpg">
```

Is there any code to put in so that as the title changes from page to page, so too will the booth number in the URL automatically. Is there a way to do this within a URL?

Comment: That link is not functioning. Please how exactly do you want to put this? Do you have a snippet?

Comment: @RahulDwivedi – I updated with code snippet but it's not a functioning link because it is just an example. I am looking to grab the text within the <title> tag and put it in the src URL "...com/page-title-here/images/picture1.jpg"

Comment: are you using any framework? `var src='https://mywebsite.com/' + document.title + '/images/picture1.jpg';` this will give you a dynamic url

Comment: Although there is a way to do this, I'd recommend finding a way your framework (if any) / stack has a simpler / more robust way to pass the data instead of using the title tag. What framework / stack are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this. When the document is ready it will find the page title and edit the url of the picture!

```js
$('img').attr('src', 'https://www.mywebsite.com/'+ document.title +'/images/picture1.jpg');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/booth106/images/picture1.jpg" alt="my image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var src='https://mywebsite.com/' + document.title + '/images/picture1.jpg';
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]; //considering you want to update the src of the first image

img.src = src;
```